# How to optimize my query with a CTE and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My query has a CTE to rank roles for each user. The second part selects all users and pivots each role into a new column.

The CTE is being joined based on id still, it's taking for ever to run the query.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
WITH UserRoles AS
(
    SELECT 
        ru.ID,
        ru.EmailAddress,
        r.RoleName,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY IdentityUserID ORDER BY UserRoleName) AS RoleNumber
    FROM
        Users ru
    LEFT JOIN 
        User_Role r ON r.UserRoleID = ru.UserRoleID
    WHERE
        ru.UserID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    l.[LastName],
    l.[FirstName],
    (SELECT TOP 1 RoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNumber = 1) AS Role1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNumber = 2) AS Role2,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNumber = 3) AS Role3,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNumber = 4) AS Role4,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNumber = 5) AS Role5
FROM 
    [dbo].[UserLogins] l
WHERE
    (SELECT TOP 1 UserRoleName 
     FROM UserRoles 
     WHERE UserRoles.ID = l.ID AND RoleNum = 1) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Seems like a `VALUES` clause would be way better. Why does every subquery have `TOP 1` too without an `ORDER BY` too? Are you happy with random results?

Comment: The order by is already being done in the cte.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: You can't use an `ORDER BY` in a CTE, so the CTE isn't determining it. `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` effectively means, to the data engine, return what ever row you find first, I don't care what.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Unless you have repeat user roles you should use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` to make things clear. And you probably dont need top 1. You already passing `ID` and `RoleNumber`

Comment: The UserLogins table has about 168,000 rows.
currently it takes more than 5 mins to run the run the query. The UserLogins table has eventtime column so, I tried to limit the data to the last quarter instead of selecting everything. still it's taking more than 2:30 mins to run

Comment: My advice, @FarisAhmed: read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question with sample data and output based on that data, so that the people who are making time to help you can see how your logic **actually** works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY` rather than subqueries.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT l.LastName, l.FirstName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN RoleName END) as Role1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN RoleName END) as Role2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN RoleName END) as Role3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN RoleName END) as Role4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN RoleName END) as Role5
FROM (SELECT l.LastName, l.FirstName, u.ID, u.EmailAddress, r.RoleName,
             row_number() over (partition by IdentityUserID order by UserRoleName) AS seqnum
      FROM Users u JOIN
           User_Role ur
           ON u.UserRoleID = ur.UserRoleID JOIN
           UserLogins ul
           ON ur.id = ul.id
      WHERE u.UserID is not null
     ) r
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName;
```

Comment: thanks for your help however, using your query is only returning 111 out 168,000 rows and I believe it's due to the MAX part.

Comment: @FarisAhmed . . . I would instead guess that you are mixing up the ids in your query.  I don't know what the `id` is that is being used for the last `join` or why you care about `IdentityUserID`, but this logic follows the logic of your query.

Comment: Sorry it should  be "partition by ru.id order by UserRoleName"

Comment: @FarisAhmed . . . I don't know.  You haven't shared sample data, desired results, or explained what the query is supposed to do.  This is intended to answer your performance question.  You might want to ask a new question with more useful information.

Comment: i think all you need to do is update 1 join     "JOIN UserLogins ul
               ON ur.id = u.id"